# MySQL insert multiple rows with some values missing

Tags: mysql

Given

```
INSERT INTO tbl_name (a,b,c) VALUES(1,2,3),(4,5,6),(7,8,9);
```

is a standard form for insert, how to insert multiple rows, if some data is missing?

e.g.

```
INSERT INTO tbl_name (a,b,c) VALUES(1,'missing','missing'),(4,'missing',6),(7,8,9);
```

Note, table may contain data instead for "missing" values, and it should not be overwritten with "null" or else.

Comment: Insert `null` instead of string `'missing'`

Comment: Sorry for late note, but table data may be present already and should not be overwritten with 'null'.

Comment: Is your `a` column a primary key column? Is it an autoincrement one?

Comment: yes, a is id, but "on duplicate key update" will solve the issue

Answer (score 2):

If you want the same behavior as if the column was omitted in the insert use `default`:

```
INSERT INTO tbl VALUES (1,default,default),(4,default,6)...
```

If you want empty values just use `null`:

```
INSERT INTO tbl VALUES (1,null,null),(4,null,6)...
```

Comment: Vatev, inserting default generates error:

General error: 1366 Incorrect integer value: 'default' for column 'open_close_children' at row 1.

What can be the reason?

Comment: Did you put quotes around `default` (`'default'`)? If so - remove them.

Answer (score 0):

In that case you can insert `null` instead of `missing` :

```
INSERT INTO tbl_name (a,b,c) VALUES(1,null,null),(4,null,6),(7,8,9);
```

This solution will work only if the target fields are nullable or it will throw error

Comment: Harsh, my table may have data already in "missing" cells, which should not be overwritten with null. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

First, about what you specified:

> Note, table may contain data instead for "missing" values, and it
>   should not be overwritten with "null" or else.

In this regard, if you use only 'INSERT` statements, then it doesn't matter if some data exists already in some form, because an 'INSERT' statement inserts (!) new records, doesn't update records.

More of it: let's say you have an `id` column as a primary key column. If you try to `INSERT` a record with an 'id' identical with an existing one, then an error will arise: "Duplicate key...".

Now, let's say `id` is not a primary key value. Then, when you try to `INSERT` a new record with an 'id' identical with an existing one, then the new record will be inserted as duplicate.

That said, you can use `UPDATE` in order to update existing records. In order to not overwrite existing values, you can just omit them in `UPDATE` statement.

Example: table `users` with columns `id`, `fname`, `lname`:

```
id   fname   lname
1    John    Smith
2    Sam     Stevenson
```

`UPDATE` statement:

```
UPDATE users
SET fname='Helen'
WHERE id = 2;
```

Results:

```
id   fname   lname
1    John    Smith
2    Helen   Stevenson
```